# Q: AudiKit : AKEqualizerFilter does not work properly with iBAction

Tags: swift, audiokit

Well, I am really confused since when I change the parameters and try to start()/ bypass() a node with iBAction, but nothing happens. The oscillator(WhiteNoise) seems to work properly while the Eq doesn't. Those parameters do have changed, however, the sound remained unchanged.

and here are my codes:

```
import AudioKit

class Conductor {

    private var oscillator = AKWhiteNoise()
    public var filter = AKEqualizerFilter()

    private var gain = -12.0


    init() {
        oscillator.amplitude = 1
        oscillator.stop()

        filter = AKEqualizerFilter(oscillator)
        filter.bypass()

        AudioKit.output = filter

        do {
            try AudioKit.start()
        } catch {
            AKLog("AudioKit did not start!")
        }
    }

    func play()  {
        if oscillator.isPlaying {
            oscillator.stop()
        } else {
            oscillator.play()

        }
    }

    func bypass(centerFrequency: Double, Q: Double)  {
        if filter.isBypassed {
            filter.rampDuration = 0.3
            filter.centerFrequency = centerFrequency
            filter.bandwidth = centerFrequency/Q
            filter.gain = pow(10, gain/20)

            filter.start()
        } else {
            filter.bypass()
        }
        print(filter.isBypassed)
    }

}
```

and my calls in ViewController:

```
@IBAction func bypass(_ sender: Any) {
    conductor.bypass(centerFrequency: 125, Q: 7)
}
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with an IBAction per se, perhaps the isBypassed check is broken in AudioKit, will have to investigate.